# Handle AADSTS70008/ AADSTS50173 error codes returned from [MSAL] [.Net]

Tags: .net, error-handling, azure-ad-msal

I wanted to ask about the best and documented way to catch those error codes **AADSTS70008**/ **AADSTS50173**
 returned from MSAL in case of expired tokens/authorization codes.
Is it okay to catch them in the message of the exception or how?
cause I was debugging and I didn't find those error returned in the error code field of **MsalServiceException**